# Current alternative to the old CHECKSUM program

Tags: windows, backup, file-management, hashing, verification

I'm looking for an application that does md5/sha hash check on specific files/folders periodically and store an index file per folder for future verification. I remember such application exist in DOS days, to detect files infected by virus.

The main purpose for this is to detect corrupted copy of backup, as I understand that consumer grade hardware are not 100% error free when doing backup or file transfer from device to device. The hash can also be used to generate a list of changed files for backup.

Most of the software I can find is hash manually.

EDIT: Windows based application, preferably a shell extension which I can right click on a folder and do a checksum/verify all files in that folder. Even better if that can integrate with a backup/sync program like BeyondCopy

Comment: What platform? Windows?

Comment: @DanD. It's windows based, I've updated my question.

Comment: This sounds like TripWire. (I don’t know whether it still exists.)

Answer (score 3):

I use the md5sum software from [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or [gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki). Redirect the output of md5sum to a textfile `md5sum * > checkfile`, then check the file with `md5sum -c /path/to/checkfile`

Answer (score 3):

One option is the [File Checksum Integrity Verifier utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290), available from Microsoft.

> **Summary**
>
> The File Checksum Integrity Verifier (FCIV) is a command-prompt utility that computes and verifies cryptographic hash values of files. FCIV can compute MD5 or SHA-1 cryptographic hash values. These values can be displayed on the screen or saved in an XML file database for later use and verification.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of shell extensions for file verification. Alternately, you can directly use a backup program that incorporates MD5 validation, such as [**Create Synchronicity**](http://synchronicity.sourceforge.net/help.html):

[image: 1]

[image: 2]